# C simultaneously connect 1M clients

Tags: c, sockets, connection, limit

I am on a Red Hat 7 server and i want to make a C server to connect 1Million clients simultaneously.

`ulimit -n` output is 1000000

```
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

contains at the end

```
*         hard    nofile      1000000
*         soft    nofile      1000000
root      hard    nofile      1000000
root      soft    nofile      1000000
```

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

contains at some point

```
fs.file-max = 90000000000000
```

when i **don't run** my C server the output of my

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
```

is

```
5184    0   90000000000000
```

when i **run** my C server the output of my

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
```

is

```
116537  0   90000000000000
```

I can connect around 55000 clients and because i run the server and the clients on the same machine it means 2 file descriptors foreach client, so... i have that number 116537. But why not more, when i raised every system limit i found about that has something to do with my problem?


that's the server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int  n, pid;
   int son=0;   

   /* First call to socket() function */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0)
      {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
      }

   /* Initialize socket structure */
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5001;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
      {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
      }

   /* Now start listening for the clients, here
 *    * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
 *       * for the incoming connection
 *          */

   listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

   while (1)
   {
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
      if (newsockfd < 0)
         {
         perror("ERROR on accept");
         exit(1);
         }

      son++; 
      if(son % 1000 == 0)     
        printf("client nr %d connected with fd %d\n", son, newsockfd);

   } /* end of while */
}
```

that's the client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sockfd, portno, n;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   struct hostent *server;

   char buffer[256];

   if (argc <3) {
      fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }
   portno = atoi(argv[2]);
   server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

   if (server == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    int ionut; 
   for(ionut=0; ionut<90000; ionut++) { 
     /* Create a socket point */
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if(ionut % 1000 == 0) { 
       printf("connected 1000 sockets\n");   
      // sleep(1);
     }
     if (sockfd < 0)
     {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
     }

    /* Now connect to the server */
     if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
     {
        perror("ERROR connecting");
        exit(1);
     }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every client needs port on it's host, and nr of ports can not exceed 65536. You'll need more than one host to reach 1M of simultaneous clients.